# Using 'else' in Prolog

Tags: prolog

This is my first question and it's very important to me.
I'm trying to make a simple program. I'm new in Prolog and don't know how to use logical operators, can anyone help?
Thanks!

```
lamp(on):-energy(on).
ELSE lamp(off).
```

*Important:* I'm using SWI-Prolog.

Comment: Have you tried any Prolog tutorials or books? Exactly what kind of program are you trying to write and what have you tried? Is this for a class?

Comment: Try some starter resources. This site is more useful for when you have specific problems

Comment: There is nothing in this question that makes it obvious **what is it** that you are trying to achieve. You could at the very least include some pseudo-code in your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, if the possible arguments of the `energy/1` predicate are the same as the possible arguments of the `lamp/1` predicate, i.e. either `on` or `off`, you can simply write:

```
lamp(State) :-
    energy(State).
```

Otherwise, just follow the advice @g_a_kowalski.

Answer (score 1):

Use combination of operator `->/2` and operator `;/2`:

```
( If -> Then ; Else )
```

For example:

```
( 10 < 20 -> print(true); print(false) )
```

Or

```
lamp(X) :- ( energy(on) -> X = on; X = off) )
```